# List all the declared packages in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo, chefspec

I'm working on a infrastructure where some servers **don't have access to the internet**, so I have to push the packages to the local repo before declaring them to be installed on Chef.

However we've been on a situation where Chef failed to install a package since the package wasn't there on some boxes and it has been successful on some other boxes.

What I want to do is to run a Ruby/RSpec test before applying Chef config on the nodes to make sure the packages declared on the recipes do actually exist on the repo.

In order to do that I need to be able to list all the packages exists in the our recipes.

My question is: Is there anyway to list all the declared packages in Chef? I had a quick look at **Chef::Platform** and **[ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec)** but unfortunately couldn't find anything useful to my problem.

Do you have any idea where is the best place to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ChefSpec you can find all the packages by calling `chef_run.find_resources(:package)` inside some test. See the [source code](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/master/lib/chefspec/runner.rb). Like this:

```
require 'chefspec'

describe 'example::default' do
  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }

  it 'does something' do
    chef_run.find_resources(:package)...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could install one or more of the [community ohai plugins](http://docs.opscode.com/community_plugin_ohai.html). For example the following will return information about installed sofware:

- [debian](https://github.com/demonccc/chef-repo/blob/master/plugins/ohai/linux/dpkg.rb)
- [Redhat](https://github.com/demonccc/chef-repo/blob/master/plugins/ohai/linux/rpm.rb)
- [windows](https://github.com/timops/ohai-plugins/blob/master/win32_software.rb)

Once the plugins are enabled they will add additional node attributes that will be searchable from chef-server.